# Default notice period in Germany

Tags: germany, labor-law

I work in Germany. I have a permanent job contract.
Because of a mistake it doesn't contain a clause about the notice period in case I want to quit.
What notice period is applied in this case?
I'm a foreigner. Hold a Blue Card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were employed up to two years, the notice period is 4 weeks and starts at the 15th or last day of the month (so on May 6th, the employer can give notice starting at the 15th of May, with employment ending four weeks later).

If you were employed two years or more, the notice starts at the last day of the month, and the length if as follows:

2 years -> 1 month
5 years -> 2 months
8 years -> 3 months
10 years -> 4 months
12 years -> 5 months
15 years -> 6 months
20 years -> 7 months

There can be a probation up to six months where the notice period is 2 weeks.

Both parties can agree in a contract on a longer notice period (except the notice period that the employee has to give cannot be longer than the one of the employer). You cannot agree on a shorter notice period in a legally binding way.

Comment: Where did you find these times?

Comment: These periods are for firing someone. This does not answer the question.

Comment: 1. Google for "notice period germany". 2. Total nonsense. It is the exact answer to the question. These are the legal notice periods, for laying off an employee, or for leaving the company. Notice period for firing is zero, but you better have a very good reason (like theft, punching your boss etc. )

Comment: I used firing and laying off to be the same. I googled it and it shows those lengths for termination.

Answer (score 1):

When nothing is stated in the contract, which in itsself rather strange, then the provisions of the law apply.

A good starting point is here (german only):

https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbeitsrecht_(Deutschland)

Answer (score -3):

I don't think there's a specific legal time period you must give before quitting, but morally, you should give them ample notice unless you can't.

Comment: Sorry for the senseless down votes @simpadjo. Some people here don't like me because I pointed out things in their answers.

Comment: Your answer made me look at what Google thinks about it; that's why there's a second downvote.

Comment: There's a third downvote because this answer is basically just "idk!" topped with an impossibly vague moral admonition. If you're feeling like people don't like you, I suspect it's not personal and just that your answers are uniformly bad because they appear to be based far more on your personal interpretations than on any law.

Comment: @bdb484 Name a law that covers this then. lol There's not laws about every single thing. This is ridiculous.

Comment: If I knew German contract and employment law, I would definitely post an answer that cites the law. But I don't know the relevant law, so I didn't post an imaginary answer, so I didn't get downvoted, so I don't have to defend my nonanswer. This technique is not patented, so feel free to copy it.